# It is possible to draw "erasable" arrows and lines over image?

Tags: image, image-processing

Supose you have a image file, say myimage.png. Then you open Windows Paint and draw a red arrow to that image file and then save it. When you open that image again, it seems it is impossible to "delete" the red arrow so that the image file could return to its original.

But, I ask, is it actually possible do "delete" the arrow and others things drawed over the image? Could we have a image with two layers, the first imutable and the second been the place where we draw lines, arrows and so on, so that we only edit this second image on top of the the layers stack? If so, where should I start to search for? I am completely lost. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Not in png format, no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible if you create a new file format that saves the original image and also all modifications made to it. Note that this could take up a lot of disc space depending on how many modifications were made and how you actually save the made modifications. Also, depending on wether or not you actually save the last state of the modified image it could take some time to open such image because all of the operations would be required to be applied to the original image again. If, of course, you save the latest state of the image, you could easily just loading that state.

But i am not aware of any common file format that performs such task, so you may have to write you own implementation on that. [GIMPs XCF file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCF_(file_format)) does not save every action performed on the image, but it is able to save *"among others, each layer, the current selection, channels, transparency, paths and guides."* If each of the mentioned arrows would be actually added to an own layer, then you would be able to simply delete the respective layer and thus remove the arrow.

Comment: Both PhotoShop and Gimp have file formats like that. Gimp is open source, so it would be easy to use that. PDF and SVG are also file format that allow layering pixel data, but they also can layer vector data.